# No Windows Option on Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows but at first didn't have a boot option menu.

So, I installed bootrepair and ran it.

This succeeded in granting me a GRUB boot option menu, but Windows isn't on it.

Here is the bootrepair report:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8098527

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

---

EDIT:

I ran `sudo fdisk -l` and this is the output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00023fe0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   960096255   480047104   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       960098302   976771071     8336385    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       960098304   976771071     8336384   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32015679488 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62530624 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32    62530623    31265296    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like windows was completely removed (where is the ntfs disk?)  do you have a second drive? with windows or just one drive? (/dev/sda is the only drive listed in you log)

if it is just one drive you have to reinstall windows (resize your harddisk and do not delete all.  you can reinstall grub later)

Comment: I do have a second drive - this system has a couple of drives. However, when I try and boot I seemingly can't access them

Comment: on which drive is windows?  try mounting them mount  /dev/sd? /mnt

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to do that - can you give more detail?

Comment: you can use sudo blkid -o list -w /dev/null and search for ntfs  if this does not exist then you have completely killed Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Login to Ubuntu and execute from terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and please show the answer.

--

The fdisk output tell us that you have FAT32 partition at second drive: /dev/sdb1
The Windows boot loader assumes it's the first disk in the system, so 
You need to tell grub to remap the two disks as part of the Windows entry:

```
title       Windows
root        (hd1,0)
savedefault
map     (hd0) (hd1)
map     (hd1) (hd0)
chainloader +1
```

[You can use this tool, to customise grub2 entry with ease](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43471/how-to-configure-the-linux-grub2-boot-menu-the-easy-way/)

Comment: I can see that Windows must be on a totally separate harddisk, but for some reason I can't see it on the BIOS menu.